# Update HTML only where needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

Example HTML page:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then in a ajax request I get

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to update the first one without replacing it? In that particular example it should only append a list item to the UL.

But how can I determine if some needs to be added, removed etc, if I don't know what the HTML code will look like?

Comment: This is pretty odd. Why would you return HTML in an ajax request? Normally, you would just return the data, then update the elements on the page.

Comment: How about using the `append()` function `$("ul").append("<li> 3 </il>")`?

Comment: Seems cumbersome to add/remove list items depending on need, especially if the list gets really large. Maybe just replace the whole list with a new one?

Comment: it's for a form where someone can change the site look. after a option is changed the ajax thing should return the html of the current page again. so I want to update the whole page, but if possible only parts of it that changed. that way I can keep scroll positions and stuff

Comment: Take a look at some virtual DOM implementations. Although, since you're returning HTML in your AJAX response, I don't know if it'll end up being the best approach. Normally it'd be ideal if you were returning data from the AJAX e.g. [1,2], then later [1,2,3]

Comment: Why not replace it? Really not clear what the main issue is here

Comment: What if an item is removed as part of  the AJAX call?

Comment: Couldn't you use 'document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].innerText="Updated Text";' for achieving the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your html code needs to be this way

```
<div>
  <ul id="retrivingList">
    <li id="1"> 1 </li>
    <li id="2"> 2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

your SQl Query

```
$response["ids"] = array();
$response["list"] = array();

consider you need student roll no's from student tabel to appear in drop down

$studentDetail = "SELECT * FROM  `student`  WHERE 1 LIMIT 10";
$studentDetailExe = mysql_query($studentDetail) or die ("Error :".mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($studentDetailExe)){
    array_push($response["ids"],$data["rollNo"]);
    array_push($response["list"],"<li>".$data["rollNo"]."</li>");
 }

*rollNo is column name in student tabel
```

Your js code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "trialDataRetrival.php",
    method: "POST",

})

.done(function(response) {
    var details = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    $("ul#retrivingList").children("li").each(function(event){
        if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'),details.ids) >= 0){

        }else{
          //$.inArray() gives the position of element in the array 
          $("ul#retrivingList").append(details.list[$.inArray($(this).val(),details.ids)]);
        }
    });
})

.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
       console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      alert("Request Failed");
});  });
```